# TypeScript Not Recognising Exported Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

## Problem Intro

I have over a hundred Firebase Cloud Functions, and to keep the code organised, I split them into separate files per function (e.g., `userFunctions`, `adminFunctions`, `authFunctions`, ...) as per the instructions in the [official Firebase thread](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions).

In my `index.ts` I import all the different function files as:

```
import * as adminFunctions from './modules/adminFunctions';
import * as userFunctions from './modules/userFunctions';
...

exports.adminFunctions = adminFunctions;
exports.userFunctions = userFunctions;
...
```

In my `userFunctions.ts` file, I would declare the individual functions, some of which would call additional reusable functions from `authFunctions.ts`

**userFunctions.ts**

```
import { https } from 'firebase-functions';
import { performAppCheckAuthentication } from './supportingFunctions/authFunctions';

exports.deleteExpiredOrganisationMembershipInvite = https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    // Perform AppCheck authentication
    performAppCheckAuthentication(data, context)

    // More code
    ...
})
```

The cross-referenced `authFunctions.ts` would look like this:

```
exports.performAppCheckAuthentication = function (
    data: { [key: string]: any },
    context: CallableContext
) {
    
    return true; // There would be actual logic here in the real code
}
```

---

## Exact Issue

When I have TypeScript try to compile this code, it gives me the following error in the `userFunctions.ts` file in the import statement:

> Module '"./supportingFunctions/authFunctions"' has no exported member
> 'performAppCheckAuthentication'.

How can I keep my code split into different files to retain maintainability, but also get around this issue of not being able to import the functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the export statement instead of the `exports` global:

```
export function performAppCheckAuthentication(
    data: { [key: string]: any },
    context: CallableContext
) {
    
    return true; // There would be actual logic here in the real code
}

export const deleteExpiredOrganisationMembershipInvite = https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    // Perform AppCheck authentication
    performAppCheckAuthentication(data, context)

    // More code
    ...
})
```

[Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)